# Firefox redirect with post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, redirect

My script works fine under chrome, but not under Firefox. Firefox simply shows me a white screen. The redirection must happen with POST.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[ 

        var redirect = function(url, method) {
            var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.method = method;
            form.action = url;
            form.submit();
        };

        redirect('/mywebservice/mainpage', 'post');

        //]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try actually adding a hidden input to the form, and adding the form to the DOM before you submit it.

Comment: There's a pretty simple plugin [**here**](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js) that does the same thing cross browser

Comment: @adeneo Yes, include jQuery for a "small" problem.

Comment: @A1rPun - who said anything about including jQuery, it's 50 lines of really simple javascript, most of it native, so just extract as needed, no need to include the plugin.

Comment: @adeneo — By the time you rewrite the jQuery stuff to be native, and remove the parts of the plugin that do things that aren't needed to solve this problem … you end up with the code in the question!

Comment: @Quentin - Yes, basically, but with a hidden input and appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't submit a form that isn't part of the page.

Add `document.body.appendChild(form);` before you try to submit it.

You can't do that before the body exists though. Add a `<body>` start tag before the script. In future, also run your code through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Can you please tell me where to add this line? I am a complete noob :(

Comment: Immediately before the line where you try to submit it. i.e. before the line with `submit()` in it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Not just under FF, it gives me a white page on chrome as well. Is there a dependency or my script + your line should work right away? thanks!

Comment: @Vadganaj — There was another problem. You never start the body element, so you can't append to it. Add one.